# Converting a Dataframe to a scala Mutable map doesn't produce equal number of records

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, dataframe, collections

I am new to Scala/spark. I am working on Scala/Spark application that selects a couple of columns from a hive table and then converts it into a Mutable map with the first column being the keys and second column being the values. For example:

```
+--------+--+
| c1     |c2|
+--------+--+
|Newyork |1 |
|   LA   |0 |
|Chicago |1 | 
+--------+--+
```

will be converted to `Scala.mutable.Map(Newyork -> 1, LA -> 0, Chicago -> 1)`

Here is my code for the above conversion:

```
 val testDF = hiveContext.sql("select distinct(trim(c1)),trim(c2) from default.table where trim(c1)!=''")
 val testMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map(testDF.map(r => (r(0).toString,r(1).toString)).collectAsMap().toSeq: _*)
```

I have no problem with the conversion. However, when I print the counts of rows in the `Dataframe` and the size of the `Map`, I see that they don't match:

```
println("Map - "+testMap.size+" DataFrame - "+testDF.count)
//Map - 2359806 DataFrame - 2368295
```

My idea is to convert the `Dataframes` to `collections` and perform some comparisons. I am also picking up data from other tables, but they are just single columns. and I have no problem converting them to `ArrayBuffer[String]` - The counts match.

I don't understand why I am having a problem with the `testMap`. Generally, the counts rows in the `DF` and the size of the `Map` should match, right?

Is it because there are too many records? How do I get the same number of records in the `DF` into the `Map`?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the mismatch in counts is caused by elimination of duplicated keys (i.e. city names) in `Map`.  By design, `Map` maintains unique keys by removing all duplicates.  For example:

```
val testDF = Seq(
  ("Newyork", 1),
  ("LA", 0),
  ("Chicago", 1),
  ("Newyork", 99)
).toDF("city", "value")

val testMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map(
  testDF.rdd.map( r => (r(0).toString, r(1).toString)).
    collectAsMap().toSeq: _*
)
// testMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String] =
//   Map(Newyork -> 99, LA -> 0, Chicago -> 1)
```

You might want to either use a different collection type or include an identifying field to your Map key to make it unique.  Depending on your data processing need, you can also aggregate data into a Map-like dataframe via `groupBy` like below:

```
testDF.groupBy("city").agg(count("value").as("valueCount"))
```

In this example, the total of `valueCount` should match the original row count.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was wondering how can there be duplicates when I am selecting the values using the hive's `distinct` function. I later noticed that there were commas in the values and used `regexp_replace` to remove all the commas. But I still don't understand how there can be so many duplicates in the first place. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Standard SQL applies keyword `distinct` to the combination of all columns in the `select` clause regardless of how you group the columns.  In other words, `select distinct(col_a), col_b ...` is no difference from `select distinct col_a, col_b ...` hence only guarantees `col_a + col_b` is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you add entries with duplicate key to your map, duplicates are automatically removed. So what you should compare is:

```
println("Map - "+testMap.size+" DataFrame - "+testDF.select($"c1").distinct.count)
```